# A quadratic form with operations from different fields?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, finite-fields, quadratic-forms

Consider a standard quadratic form:

$$f(x) = x^TAx$$

where $A \in 
\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $x \in \{0,1\}^n \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. In this function, all operations are carried out over $\mathbb{R}$. Evaluating this function will require $O(n^2)$ operations.

Now it turns out that the $x$ is generated via a linear operation over $GF(2)$.

$$x = Gx'$$

where $G \in \mathbb{F}_2^{n\times m}$, and $x' \in \mathbb{F}_2^{m}$, and $m \ll n$. We extend $x$ to a vector over the reals by equating the additive and multiplicative identities in the natural way.

If we exploit this in the quadratic form, we have

$$f(x') = (x')^TG^TAGx'$$

Assume $G$ and $A$ are given a-priori and any pre-processing of them is free. Since there are operations over different fields, it's not clear if we can compute $f(x')$ in $O(m^2)$ operations, but I am wondering if it is possible.

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: I'm not convinced that $(x^{\prime})^{T}G^{T}AGx^{\prime}$ will even **be** a quadratic form with this mix of operations from different fields, at least in any meaningful sense of the word (since $x^{\prime} \mapsto Gx^{\prime}$ will not be an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map).

Comment: @MorganRodgers, I have thought about this quite a bit, and I believe you are right. Since we don't have associativity, I don't think it is possible to do this computation in $O(m^2)$. Though, I also noticed that my formulation makes little sense without a memory constraint, since $x'$ is from a finite set, we can simply pre-compute all the values, and do a lookup in $O(1)$.